# C++ preprocessor token pasting for namespace qualification

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

I am having trouble with the preprocessor token pasting operator in gcc 4.7.1 (std=c++11). Namely, consider the following code:

```
// Create a name for a global map (this works)
#define GLOBAL_MAP(name) g_map_ ## name // This works fine

// Now, namespace qualify this map (this fails to compile when used)
#define NS_QUAL_GLOBAL_MAP(name) SomeNamespace:: ## GLOBAL_MAP(name)
```

Usage scenarios - first the map definitions:

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> GLOBAL_MAP(my_map);

namespace SomeNamespace
{

std::map<std::string,std::string> GLOBAL_MAP(my_map);

}
```

Now the usage:

```
void foo()
{
    bar(GLOBAL_MAP(my_map)); // This compiles fine
    baz(NS_QUAL_GLOBAL_MAP(my_map)); // This fails to compile with:
                                     // error: pasting "::" and "NAME_MAP" does not give a
                                     // valid preprocessing token
}
```

What I believe might be happening is that it is interpreting `GLOBAL_MAP` after `##` as a token for pasting rather than a macro to be further expanded. How do I get around this?

Comment: Why would someone downvote a perfectly legitimate C++ preprocessor question/mistake? The arrogance of some people astounds me.

Comment: I think it doesn't show any research effort and isn't useful. The error gives the answer: `pasting "::" and "NAME_MAP" does not give a valid preprocessing token"`. Reading the error seems like the minimum research you should undertake when faced with a compiler error.

Comment: @Jonathan, I read the error and I understood the error. I just wasn't sure why I was getting the error. When this was explained by the accepted answer, it became glaringly obvious that I had added a sort of preprocessor "level of indirection," in a manner of speaking, where one was not warranted. Downvoting this sort of question shows nothing but arrogance. We all make mistakes when we program and inquiring about them here, even if they are the result of a temporary mind-fart, is what StackOverflow is all about.

Comment: And I don't think a temporary mind-fart makes for a good question that will help others in future. You asked the question, and got the answer, great. But I don't think solving temporary mind-farts adds very much useful to the site long-term. When problems are the result of a simple typo that's a valid close reason, and I think a simple mistake that is easily corrected is almost in the same category. (And that's not to mention that you **didn't post a MCVE** as required for "why isn't this code working?" questions, which is another reason to close and/or downvote).

Comment: For record, noting the comments by @JonathanWakely, I thought this question was very useful ~3 yrs later. The real question is "what's the workaround?" and the answer provide that nicely. Not every question needs to be earth-shaking to be useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Token pasting generates a *single* token for the compiler to read. This isn’t what you want here — `::` is a valid C++ token on its own, but `::g_map_my_map` isn’t a token that the compiler knows.

Hence, remove the token pasting operator:

```
#define NS_QUAL_GLOBAL_MAP(type) SomeNamespace::GLOBAL_MAP(type)
```

Comment: Blah! What was I thinking :)? +1! Deferred checkmark for you and more coffee for me...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `##` operator after `::`.  The `##` operator is used to form a *single* token, but `SomeNamespace::g_map_mymap` are multiple tokens anyway.  Just do

```
#define NS_QUAL_GLOBAL_MAP(type) SomeNamespace::GLOBAL_MAP(type)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want `SomeNamespace:: GLOBAL_MAP(name)`.

You can't join a name like `g_map_my_map` to the `::` token, because `::g_map_my_map` is not a valid token, it's two tokens. So just put them next to each other, don't try to join them.